# Angular module not updated after pushing to CloudFoundry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloud-foundry, meanjs

I'm working on a small crud app which I started with mean.js and push to a cloudfoundry app. Today I made a few changes, and after pushing to cloud foundry with `cf push` the few changes I made to the home view - `home.client.view.html` showed up correctly, but a new route I added and the new menu item to go along with it are not showing up. All of these changes work fine locally and pass tests, but after pushing only the static views are updated on the live site. There are no errors from CF on the push.

The menu and route are very close to the default examples in mean.js:

```
/* books.client.routes.js */

angular.module('books').config(['$stateProvider',
  function ($stateProvider) {
    // Books state routing
    $stateProvider
      .state('books', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/books',
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        data: {
          roles: ['user', 'admin']
        }
      })
      .state('books.list', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'modules/books/views/list-books.client.view.html'
      })
      ......
  }
]);




/* books.client.config.js */

angular.module('books').run(['Menus',
  function (Menus) {
    // Add the books dropdown item
    Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', {
      title: 'Books',
      state: 'books',
      type: 'dropdown'
    });

    // Add the books dropdown item
    Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', {
      title: 'New Book',
      state: 'books.create'
    });

    // Add the dropdown list item
    Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'books', {
      title: 'Classmate Bookshelf',
      state: 'books.list'
    });

    Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'books', {
      title: 'Your Bookshelf',
      state: 'books.yourbooks'
    });

    Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'books', {
      title: 'Find A Book',
      state: 'books.search'
    });

    Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'books', {
      title: 'New Book',
      state: 'books.create'
    });
  }
]);
```

To check to see if I missed something, I made another change to the home view, then removed *all* of the menu options and when cloudfoundry finished building the home view was again updated but the menu options were still there, which leads me to think it has nothing to do with any of the changes I've made and something to do with what I'm pushing to CF.

It seems like a caching issue but the searching I've done hasn't come up with anything for clearing CF cache.

I did try to restart and restage the droplet, which didn't change anything.

I also thought it might be something getting ignored by cloudfoundry, but the only things in my cfignore are:

```
tmp/
log/
node_modules/
.sass-cache/
```

I've made changes to this site before so I'm sure this is a really simple issue, I'm just stumped because almost all of my edits are updated fine, besides anything related to menu/routes. Thanks an advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Are you sure it's not a browser caching issue?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that's the first thing I thought. Not only cleared cookies/cache/incognito, but also tried different browsers and had the same problem.

Comment: This question might require a bit more back-and-forth debugging.  You may wish to open a GitHub issue: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/issues.  I would check in the browser to see if the javascript asset being served up is the old code or new.  While making requests you can do `cf logs app_name` to see if there's any indication of what it's serving.  Might also want to try pushing the same code as a new app, to see if at least that is working.